# How to call method with EventHandler parameter using expression trees?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Consider this simple piece of code. **How can this be done using expression trees?**

```cs
ErrorsChangedEventManager.AddHandler(obj, obj.SomeHandler);
```

Here's a small sample illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish. (Add a reference to `WindowBase` to make it compile.)

```cs
class Program : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p1 = new Program { Id = 1 };
        var p2 = new Program { Id = 2 };

        // Here is the root of the problem.
        // I need to do this INSIDE the expression from a given instance of Program.
        EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> handler = p1.OnError;
        var handlerConstant = Expression.Constant(handler);

        var mi = typeof(ErrorsChangedEventManager).GetMethod(nameof(ErrorsChangedEventManager.AddHandler), 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(INotifyDataErrorInfo), "source");
        var program = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Program), "program");

        // This will work, but the OnError method will be invoked on the wrong instance.
        // So, I need to get the expression to perform what would otherwise be easy in code...
        // E.g. AddHandler(someObject, p2.OnError);
        var call = Expression.Call(mi, source, handlerConstant);

        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Action<INotifyDataErrorInfo, Program>>(call, source, program);
        var action = expr.Compile();
        action.DynamicInvoke(p1, p2);

        p1.ErrorsChanged.Invoke(p1, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
    }

    void OnError(object sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Program p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OnError called for Id={Id}. Expected Id=2");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName) => Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    public bool HasErrors => false;
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't work. I somehow need to provide the `OnError` handler as a *parameter* to the call.

Comment: You switch from `EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>` to `DataErrorsChangedEventArgs` when you create the `Expression.Lambda`. Stay with `EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>` and you should be fine?

Comment: I'm missing something more. The creation of the lambda fails with: `System.ArgumentException: 'ParameterExpression of type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyDataErrorInfo' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object''`

Comment: Your `source` parameter is of type `Program`, so your `Action` needs to be an `Action<Program, EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>>` (to make it more general, your `source` should be `typeof(INotifyDataErrorInfo)`, and your `Action` should be `Action<INotifyDataErrorInfo, EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>>`

Comment: Well, if I can use `p.OnError` in code, then I am able to build a lambda. The problem is to build the expression tree for "p.OnError" given an argument of type `Program´, for any instance...

Comment: I don't follow. Can you give an example of how you want to use this?

Comment: `compiledDelegate.Invoke(notifyDataErrorInfoInstance, programInstanceWithCallback);`

Comment: Can you give an example which contains enough information for someone to work out what you're doing? What is `notifyDataErrorInfoInstance`? Is it an instance of `Program`? How does that differ from `programInstanceWithCallback`? What is the data type of `programInstanceWithCallback`?

Comment: Please see updated sample code. It clearly illustrates the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: So your question is how to take a `Program` instance, and access its `OnError` method (as a delegate)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clear enough :)

Comment: Please provide an _actual_ [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do. Provide both the non-expression version of the code that produces the behavior you want, as well as the expression-based version that you are having trouble getting to work. Explain precisely what the difficulty in the latter is. **Make sure both versions can actually be compiled and run as standalone code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the easiest thing to do is to create a lambda which creates the `EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>` for you, and then use `Expression.Invoke` to call it:

```
public class Program : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var p1 = new Program { Id = 1 };
        var p2 = new Program { Id = 2 };

        var mi = typeof(ErrorsChangedEventManager).GetMethod(nameof(ErrorsChangedEventManager.AddHandler),
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(INotifyDataErrorInfo), "source");
        var program = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Program), "program");

        Expression<Func<Program, EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>>> createDelegate = p => p.OnError;
        var createDelegateInvoke = Expression.Invoke(createDelegate, program);

        var call = Expression.Call(mi, source, createDelegateInvoke);
        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Action<INotifyDataErrorInfo, Program>>(call, source, program);
        var action = expr.Compile();

        action(p1, p2);

        p1.ErrorsChanged.Invoke(p1, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
    }

    public void OnError(object sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Program p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OnError called for Id={Id}. Expected Id=2");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName) => Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    public bool HasErrors => false;
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
}
```

If you look at the DebugView for `createDelegate`, you can see that the compiler created:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Program,System.EventHandler`1[System.ComponentModel.DataErrorsChangedEventArgs]]>(Program $p)
{
    (System.EventHandler`1[System.ComponentModel.DataErrorsChangedEventArgs]).Call .Constant<System.Reflection.MethodInfo>(Void OnError(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.DataErrorsChangedEventArgs)).CreateDelegate(
        .Constant<System.Type>(System.EventHandler`1[System.ComponentModel.DataErrorsChangedEventArgs]),
        $p)
}
```

You could construct this expression yourself if you wanted, by getting the `MethodInfo` for `OnError`, then calling `CreateDelegate` on it.

---

All of that said, you can just use a lambda to do all of that:

```
Expression<Action<INotifyDataErrorInfo, Program>> test = (source, program) =>
    ErrorsChangedEventManager.AddHandler(source, program.OnError);
```

Comment: Using that `Expression<Func<>>` trick certainly makes things easier!